# Not able to install python-pip in kali linux 2019.3 vbox amd 64 with apt-get install python-pip

Tags: python, pip, kali-linux

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

I tried updating my source file with the following commands:

```
leafpad /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Remove everything and passed the following lines:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Save and quit then did

```
apt-get update
apt-get update --fix-missing
apt autoremove
```

then

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python-pip
```

I still get the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to install it manually.

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

**Remeber to check the python version with `python --version` to check if that's the one you want. If it prints `2.7` and you want Python 3, your command may be `python3`**

Comment: root@kali:~# python --version
Python 2.7.16+
root@kali:~# wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
root@kali:~# python get-pip.py
  File "get-pip.py", line 1
    --2020-04-17 07:49:01--  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
root@kali:~# python3 get-pip.py
  File "get-pip.py", line 1
    --2020-04-17 07:49:01--  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid token

Comment: i got the above error so i tried using python3 but it still doesnt work

Comment: Paste your `python --version` output

Comment: i pasted it above its:  root@kali:~# python --version Python 2.7.16+    so i used python in my command it ddnt work so i also tried using python3 it also did not work

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it. Have you tried `python -m ensurepip`?

Comment: thank you so much it worked actually the get-pip file was not saved as get-pip.py it was stored with the name get-pip.py.1 so i ran the command again:python get-pip.py.1 and it worked and pip was sucessfully installed thanks for your help appretiate it:)

Comment: That's great! Have a nice day